# Redirecting requests to non-exisiting file to another directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a site, that has many requests to `index.html`, but there isn't such file in my root directory. I want to redirect all these requests to a certain file in another directory.

That another directory URL is very long (like: `wp-content/themes/wp-mobile/...../index.html`) and I don't want users see this long directory directly. I'd like to present some kind of short URL instead, like `site.com/adasd`,

How can I achieve this, using `.htaccess` file and `mod-rewrite`?

Answer (score 0):

First redirect `/index.html` to your shortened URL of choice as

```
Redirect 301 /index.html /adasd
```

Then map the shortened URL to the actual page without redirection as

```
RedirectRule ^adasd/?$ /wp-content/themes/wp-mobile/...../index.html [NC,L]
```

You may also need to add the following to handle any css, js file references  properly.

```
RedirectRule ^adasd/(.+)$ /wp-content/themes/wp-mobile/...../$1 [NC,L]
```

If being added together, you can shorten the above two rules as

```
RedirectRule ^adasd/?$ /adasd/index.html [NC]
RedirectRule ^adasd/(.+)$ /wp-content/themes/wp-mobile/...../$1 [NC,L]
```

---

Try this instead:

```
RedirectRule ^index\.html$ /adasd [NC,L,R=301]

RedirectRule ^adasd/?$ /adasd/index.html [NC]
RedirectRule ^adasd/(.+)$ /wp-content/themes/wp-mobile/...../$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: hi, thanks alot mr Ravi Thapiyal. I try it but it didn't works it directly redirects to that long url :( , is this scenario possible in this way that i told ?

Comment: Check my update. Post your current .htaccess code if this doesn't work.

Comment: hi , thank you for your answer Ravi Thapliyal. the Internal server error happens. RewriteEngine is on , but ...   i think my scenario is wrong and it cant implement just by htaccess